# Unslider infinite scroll? Github demo code breaks the slider dots

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, unslider

Has anyone been able to get infitite scrolling working using Unslider?

http://unslider.com/

Apparently, the dev branch on github has code that include infinite scroll (where the scroller always scrolls to the left and doesnt jump back to slide 1), but I cant get this to work at all.

When I incorporate the code from github, it works for the infinite scroll, but it breaks the pagination dots.

Dots show, but are all out of order.

I currently have 5 slides:

On first load, slide 1 and dot 1 is active

On slide 2, dot 3 is active

On slide 3, dot 4 is active

On slide 4, dot 5 is active

On slide 5, dot 5 is active

After repeat, on slide 1, dot 5 is active.

Anyone know of any working examples online? I have searched but cant find any - anyone asking this question just gets referred back to github again.

I have also opened an issue on github for this, but if anyone knows of a working example, that would be useful to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to knock something together by adding a check on what image is currently active, and then forcing the visible dot index to the correct position with a few 'if' statements, and this works ok.

Until an 'official' answer / fix is released for this, if anyone else wants to see a fully working infinite scroll slider example based on the unslider code, then I will provide a link to my working example.